# Flutter Image not shrinking when window gets smaller

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter image that is not shrinking as the window shrinks:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Column(
        //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 500, maxWidth: 600),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/DontForgetTheSpoon-largeLogo.jpg',
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I tried to use boxFit.contain in the Image.Asset but that didn't seem to work out for me. Anything else I should be looking into?

This widget is inside other widgets just for SA.

Comment: Where did you indicate that you want the image to be smaller if the page gets smaller?  I don't see anything that would suggest that.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to figure out. I thought it would shrink with the column it was in.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `fit` property of `image Widget`, inorder to have image shrink try use value `BoxFit.contain`:

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
  child: Image.asset(
    'images/DontForgetTheSpoon-largeLogo.jpg',
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
  ),
),
```

Comment: I mentioned I tried that already and it didnt work.